# Show/Hide a visual on Power BI based on a measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

i want to hide a table **(Visual)** based on a measure .

per exemple if my measure equal to january or february i want to hide the visual

is this trick possible on Power BI . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, this is typically handled with [buttons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-buttons) and [bookmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-bookmarks) designed to [interact together](https://radacad.com/bookmarks-and-buttons-making-power-bi-charts-even-more-interactive).

However, there are some workarounds that mask one visual with another based on a measure.

- [This example](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/show-or-hide-a-power-bi-visual-based-on-selection/) uses a card to mask a matrix.
- [This one](https://www.reportsimple.com.au/post/hide-power-bi-visual-based-on-slicer-selection) uses a treemap visual instead.

This is a fairly common request and shows up under several Power BI Ideas. Please vote and comment to increase visibility.

- [Conditional hide visuals based on value](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=52c5c1ea-80ed-4e53-a5ce-10cd9779f82e)
- [Show/Hide Visualizations based on slicer value](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=e1d462a4-156a-4123-b879-11b0ec486d85)
- [Dax measure to show/hide visual or page](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=5db60e41-550d-4234-be8f-ad670f88504c)
- [conditionally hide visual based on slicer](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=1caf8262-972a-4c99-ab8f-e81700a296c9)