# Trying to hide shape map visuals based on slicer selection in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Based on instruction that i found online I was told to use this script

```
Is Capacity Selected = 
    IF(
        SELECTEDVALUE(Selection[Column1]) == "Column" , 
        1, 
        0
    )
```

Though this works, for a shape map though the data is grayed out i still see the map. Is there a way to completely hide the visual in a slicer selection where i don't see it and feel it?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66909502